# CollapsingToolbarLayout disable background on collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I updated my dependencies to v24 but now my CollapsingToolbarLayout is broken. I used it to show an image(using setBackground) when the user didn't scroll yet, after that it would turn blue. Now it keeps showing the image and there's a white bar under it that covers my content, yet I haven't changed anything in my code. Here's an image(changed to red the background on purpose): https://i.stack.imgur.com/nflCU.jpg.
See the toolbar has an image on it instead of being a solid color?also you can see the title gets cut off by a red-colored bar under the toolbar. Here are the layouts(which are simply edited layouts from the android studio template):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewarticle_appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/article_collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_view_article" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_view_article.xml

```
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Edit: I was using v 24.0.3 of the support libraries, I updated everything to 24.2.1 and the invisible bar is gone. The background problem remains though

Comment: remove ur toolbar, you don't need that.

Comment: @HAXM if i remove it then I don't see the toolbar, yet the bar i talked about is still there

Comment: Change appbar layout height as per ur need, preferable it should be equal to height of toolbar

Comment: @HAXM that just makes the collapsinglayout not collapse, also the invisible bar is still there

Comment: By updating to 24.2.1 all my dependencies I fixed the invisible bar problem. Still the background remains when the bar is collapsed, which should not happen since I have app:contentScrim